# Modify firefox profile template

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, testing, webdriver

I want to modify a firefox template from which webdriver will create temporary profile by

```
new FirefoxDriver();
```

I am linux user (ubuntu). Anybody knows where this template is located?

Comment: Doesn't the code way of modifying the profile help i.e defining ffprofile and launching webdriver with it ....or is there something particular u need in the profile?

Answer (score 0):

We don't modify the actual file in our solution.
Granted, this is C#, but it should be very similar:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile() {AcceptUntrustedCertificates = true};
profile.SetPreference("webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer", false);
Driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
Driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```